# 2 level RSA Encryption

Tags: ios, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I have requirement in the app to do 2 level RSA encryption with 2 different public key.
1) Encrypt plainText with first public key.
2) Encrypt output of first with second public key.

I am using iOS Security framework to do the same. The first level of encryption works fine but when I try to encrypt again the output of step one with second public key the sanity check fails returning -50.
I assume this is due to the reason that buffer size is less for the required text to encrypt. But I am not sure what parameter to change to achieve the same. I tried changing padding from `kSecPaddingPKCS1` to other types but it is not giving the required output.

Following is my function for the encryption:

```
+ (NSData*)getRSAEncryptedText:(NSString*)plaintext withPublicKeyIdSuffix:(NSString*)idSuffix {

    SecKeyRef publicKey = NULL;

    NSString *publicKeyIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier], idSuffix];
    NSData * publicTag = [publicKeyIdentifier dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSMutableDictionary *queryPublicKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:kSecClassKey forKey:kSecClass];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:publicTag forKey:kSecAttrApplicationTag];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:kSecAttrKeyType];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:kSecReturnRef];

    SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef)queryPublicKey, (CFTypeRef *)&publicKey);

    if (!publicKey)
    {
        if(publicKey) CFRelease(publicKey);

        return nil;
    }

    size_t cipherBufferSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(publicKey);

    SecPadding kTypeOfWrapPadding = kSecPaddingPKCS1;
    //  SecPadding kTypeOfWrapPadding = kSecPaddingNone;

    uint8_t* cipherBuffer = malloc( cipherBufferSize * sizeof(uint8_t) );
    memset((void *)cipherBuffer, 0x0, cipherBufferSize);

    OSStatus sanityCheck = noErr;

    // Encrypt using the public key.
    sanityCheck = SecKeyEncrypt(publicKey,
                                kTypeOfWrapPadding,
                                (const uint8_t *)[[plaintext dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] bytes],
                                [[plaintext dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] length],
                                cipherBuffer,
                                &cipherBufferSize
                                );

    if (sanityCheck != noErr) {
        //NSLog(@"error with encryption");
        free(cipherBuffer);
        return nil;
    }

    NSData *encryptedData = [NSData dataWithBytes:cipherBuffer length:cipherBufferSize];

    return encryptedData;
}
```

Please suggest how to achieve the second level of encryption.

Comment: Seems insane, but the *only* chance you have of this working at all is if 1) The second modulus is greater than the first, and 2) you use `kSecPaddingNone` for the second encryption.

Comment: -50: "One or more parameters passed to a function were not valid." Check them and find out which one. What is the size of the data output from the first encryption and the maximum size allowed to be encrypted by the second key? Keep in mind that with PKCS1 padding the input data must be 11 bytes less than SecKeyGetBlockSize.

Comment: @GregS If both moduli are close enough (for example both have 256 leading 1 bits), it will work with overwhelming probability even if the first modulus is bigger. (Though I don't get why you'd want to do that)

Comment: @GregS agreed with you but that is requirement. And yes as you mentioned in point 1) if the second public key is greater than the first it works properly, because it will satisfy the requirement of msg being smaller than the encryption key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved now, have altered the order in which keys were used for encryption. The one with smaller size is used first now for encryption and then the second one.